# Confused about Blazor server default project

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm confused about Blazor server default project.

About two years ago, I tried Blazor server 5.0 template created by Microsoft in Visual Studio 2019.

I see project layout has a 3 subprojects:

1. Blazor.Client contains the client side code
2. Blazor.Server contains ASP.NET Core Web API
3. Blazor.Share contains all shared data in 2 project above.

Now I need to create Blazor server project (version 7.0). When I created a project, there was only one project left.

And now, if we want to write something, we can write it in the `initializeAsync` method (database operation, file access etc.)
I want to know if this way is correct or not?

I don't need to write logic in Web API and use httpClient to request data, right?

Thanks for your answer, and sorry for my English.

Comment: It's **Blazor** - not "brazor" ....

Comment: That first project was _not_ "Blazor Server" but from the  "Blazor Wasm Hosted" template.  The templates have not changed by much. Google for the pros and cons of the Server and Wasm varieties.

Comment: create a new Blazor Server Project in the latest VS2022, you'll get just one project

Answer (score 0):

> About two years ago, I tried Blazor server 5.0 template created by
> Microsoft in Visual Studio 2019. I see project layout has a 3
> subprojects:Blazor.Client, Blazor.Server, Blazor.Share

You might misunderstand, The Blazor Server App template will build only one Blazor project. But the Blazor WebAssembly App template with selected the ASP.NET Core Hosted checkbox will generate a solution includes the following ASP.NET Core projects:

- "Client": The Blazor WebAssembly app.
- "Server": An app that serves the Blazor WebAssembly app and weather data to clients.
- "Shared": A project that maintains common classes, methods, and resources.

More detail information, see [ASP.NET Core Blazor project structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/project-structure?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

> if we want to write something, we can write it in the initializeAsync
> method (database operation, file access etc.) I want to know if this
> way is correct or not?

Yes, you can access the database or file in the `OnInitializedAsync()` method.

> I don't need to write logic in Web API and use httpClient to request
> data, right?

It depends on your choice, by using Web API, you can directly access the data from the API, instead of from the components/web page, if you don't want to provide this API, you can create service layer or directly access the database or file in the `OnInitializedAsync()` method. Refer to this article: [Blazor Server App CRUD With Entity Framework Core In .Net 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/blazor-crud-app-using-entity-framework-core-in-net-5/).

Comment: oh thanks for your help.
i'm Very new to brazor.